# Firefox sending two get request for a website

Tags: firefox, firefox-3

Clicking a link results in two calls for the page to the server. I install livehttp and inspected the header but can't figure out why it's sending the second request.

```
http://example.com/schedule?delete=290376

GET /schedule?delete=290376 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20110207 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://example.com/schedule
Cookie: Code=XXX; CodeHash=XXXXX

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 22:09:51 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: Code=XXXX; expires=Wed, 02-Mar-2011 00:09:52 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: CodeHash=XXXX; expires=Wed, 02-Mar-2011 00:09:52 GMT; path=/
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
http://example.com/schedule?delete=290376

GET /schedule?delete=290376 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20110207 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://example.com/schedule
Cookie: Code=XXXX; CodeHash=XXXXX

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 22:09:55 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: Code=XXX; expires=Wed, 02-Mar-2011 00:09:55 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: CodeHash=XXX; expires=Wed, 02-Mar-2011 00:09:55 GMT; path=/
Location: http://example.org/schedule?errors=5
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you didn't find your solution:

I have stumbled on that same issue, and it seems to be related to the page encoding. If FireFox downloads a page containing invalid characters (for example, utf-8 chars inside a page for which the Content-type header is something else), then it will download the page a second time and parse it in the encoding it has tried to guess from the invalid chars it detected in the first page.

So make sure your page either returns the correct Content-type header, or contains a meta http-equiv header with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't happen to be using firefox, have the web developer toolbar and also have the display page validation on do you?

I am guessing in the dark here as to your enviro but my team and I have been able to demonstrate that having that tool bar installed in firefox and having page validation set to display actually duplicates the POSTs and GETs as it sends that same page data to the validation service.

Comment: Nope running completely stock. I installed it to try and debug this

Comment: hmm shoot, ok but you are using FireFox? Here is another option that might be happening. Any element in your html that contains an empty src attribute will, in FireFox, invoke a call to the same page. In IE it invokes a call to the current working directory. A long shot but perhaps check for empty src tags on the page submitting the GETs

Comment: Nope all the src calls go to a static domain. Am using Firefox and have tested on linux and windows. Chrome preforms correctly on the same page

Comment: As far as I can tell, IE, Safari and Chrome all work as expected.

Comment: Not to repeat the same advice, but make sure that you don't have any kind of toolbars, add-ons or other developer type tools that are running in FF.  Experience dictates that a double submit is most often because of one of those tools running an inspection on the page, such as a DOM inspector or W3C Validator.  Particularly if you are not having the same issue with other browsers you can assume that the issue is in FF and not your application.

Comment: It's been tested on two separate machines. There are no toolbars installed.

Comment: ok next step can you share some of the code with us, specifically the post controllers?

Comment: I'm seeing the same situation, using FF4, in a Sinatra app. Neither Chrome or Safari is displaying this issue, and it's happening on any GET request I submit. It's not happening on any POST requests. Happy to post more info that seems relevant.

Comment: Update: I turned Firebug off; it seemed to resolve the issue; turning Firebug back on didn't re-enable the issue. So ... try restarting Firebug if you have it running? (Could be a red herring, I know, but I can't think of any other changes I enacted.)